# How to disallow uploading executable files using Ruby UploadedFile?

Tags: ruby, file-io, ruby-grape, actiondispatch

I'm using `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new` with my `Grape` project to upload files.

I'm not using any gem like `paperclip` to the job and I want to validate the file type and not to allow executable files.

From the documentarians seems I can use `#content_type` to check out the content of the file.

Is there any simple way to do the validation and where can I find a list of executable extensions?

Comment: You can do `f = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new`, then `File.executable?(f.path)` ?

Comment: or to `File.extname(f.original_filename)`.. This will help you to get the file extension.

Comment: File.executable? f.content_type

Comment: Eki -- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-executable-3F ( I think, it needs the file path). I think you want to use extension name.

Comment: `File.executable?` based on current user RW access.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Which one helped you ? :)